# New struct in lua module is inaccessible during compiling stage

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I'm newby in lua scripting. Trying to export some existing c++ class into lua extending with extra struct and methods.

```
%module custom_matching

%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_pair.i"

%inline %{
#include "Matching.h"
%}

%typemap(out) boost::optional<double> %{
if($1)
    $result = *$1;
else {
    $result = nil;
}
%}

namespace Matching{
        class Matching {
            public:
            Matching(double someArg = 1e-4);

            boost::optional<double> onMsg(double forwardDistance = 0.);

            void setVerbose(bool verbose);
        };

        %extend Matching {    
            boost::optional<double> onPoseMsg(const Custom3dPoint &pose) {
                std::cout << "onPoseMsg\n";
                return boost::none;
            }
        }

        struct Custom3dPoint {
            double x, y, z;
        };
}
```

First of all I recieved error message
error: ‘Custom3dPoint’ has not been declared.

Also I'd like to know if wrapping around boost::optional will work properly in lua and default arguments will be used on instancing a class.

Swig 3.0

Comment: It is declared *after* use.

Comment: declaring after use doesn't change compiling errors. Also, I've figured out from tutorials, that after use declaration works well for typemap at least